# how to use set define off in liquibase sql format

Tags: html, oracle, liquibase

I have an HTML file to be stored in the database. I am using Liquibase for this but in HTML I have lot of `&nbsp;` instances.

The problem is that SQL does not allow `&` to run without `set define off` option.

I got to know the below solutions from the net:

- I have read that I can use `cdata`, but here I am inserting HTML in Liquibase SQL format and not the XML format, so I think it is not of use.
- As there are lot of `&nbsp;` in the file, I cannot use ASCII characters for each to avoid `&`.

Error from Liquibase execution:

```
SEVERE 6/7/17 11:30 AM:liquibase: Error executing SQL set define off
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: **SQL\*Plus** (and SQL Developer) treat an ampersand specially by default, for substitution variables, and they have the `set define` command to control that behaviour. That is nothing to do with **SQL**. Other clients may mimic that behaviour. Are you actually having a problem with Liquibase, and if so can you edit your question to show what is actually happening?

Comment: @Alex, I have added liquibase error log

Comment: Right, because [`set define off` is a SQL*Plus client command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG073). If you remove that from your script does Liquibase actually complain about the data you're inserting - does it have a problem with the ampersands?

Comment: @Alex, I have tried executing query in SQL developer but it is not executing and asking for substitution variables. For Liquibase , I have not tried query without set define off . Do you mean , Liquibase will execute query without it? Shall i try it?

Comment: SQL Developer (and SQL\*Plus, ans SQLcl) have the concept of substitution variables, and have the `set define` command to control those. So you need to turn it off for those. Liquibase is not the same and the command isn't relevant there. Of course, try it in Liquibase without that `set define off`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set define off` that Liquibase is complaining about is not SQL, [it is a SQL*Plus client command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG073):

> **SET DEF[INE] {& | c | ON | OFF}**
>
> Sets the character used to prefix substitution variables to c.
>
> ON or OFF controls whether SQL*Plus will scan commands for substitution variables and replace them with their values. ON changes the value of c back to the default '&', not the most recently used character. The setting of DEFINE to OFF overrides the setting of the SCAN variable.

It is used by [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) and [SQLcl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html) as well. All of those clients use it to control the behaviour of [substitution variables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB).

Liquibase clearly doesn't recognise that client command, so it should be removed from your script.

Comment: Alex, thank you for your response.As from my question I want to use ampersand nbsp; in query but without using set define off , sql execution is throwing error  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated , so if Liquibase ignores (set define off) how can i include special characters in liquibase, do you aware of anything?

Comment: @Khushi - why do you think `ORA-01756` is related to the ampersands? Sounds more likely to be related to how you've handled single quotes. (Have you, for instance, escaped single quotes in your script to make it run in SQL Developer and Liquibase doesn't require that either? Or added/missed a quote when moving the script from SQL Devleoper to Liquibase? Pretty hard to guess without a reproducible example. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: it may be due semicolon used in & nbsp; as same error i was getting for margin: 0; but when i changed it margin: 0' || CHR(59) || ' , error switched to next line  which has & nbsp; , same query is working on sql developer with (set define off ) .I do not thing it is problem of missing single quote. I cant use ' || CHR(59) || ' for every semicolon in nbsp

Comment: Without seeing what you';re actually doing in Liquibase it's hard to tell what's happening, It sounds like you either aren't passing a string in properly, or Liquibase is assuming a semicolon - even inside a string?? - is a statement separator. Maybe ask a new question showing what you are actually doing in Liquibase, with a small sample that demonstrates the issue. It doesn't seem to be anything to do with your original question here though.

Comment: thanks for your response . Yes I agree question's title doesn't matches with my requirement .But my question description say it all .I am accepting your answer which clarifies bit of part.

Answer (score 0):

As & in &(ampersand)nbsp; is considered as substitution variable in sql and liquibase ignores set define off statement , so I used ascii characters to use & in sql query defined in liquibase as below:

&(ampersand)nbsp;  changed to ' || '&' || 'nbsp' || CHR(59) || ' and query worked